# Is it possible to you use something from database in a class tag in JSP?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, taglib

Im trying to get something out of my database to add to a class in my JSP.

```
<div class="selection <c:out value='${bill.category}'/>">

<c:forEach items="${bills}" var="bill">
        <div class="selection <c:out value='${bill.category}'/>">
            <p><c:out value="${bill.name}"/></p>
            <div class="plus-icon">
                <ion-icon size="large" name="add-circle-outline</ion-icon
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can do that by using `jstl` tag like below :

```
<c:set var="category" value="${bill.category}"/>
```

And then use above in `div` like below :

```
   <!--will print whatever is there in category-->
    <div class="selection${category}">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and know i know something new that i can use in my code.